# OAF How to add advance table with search field to standard existing page (EBS 12.1)?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-ebs

Question as in the subject:
OAF How to add advance table with search field to standard existing page (EBS 12.1)? Do you have any examples?

Comment: please explicit the acronym you use. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: @yunandtidus it'll be "Oracle Application Framework" but the question still doesn't make any sense

Comment: I have a standard page which I want to extend. I need to add a search field and tables to display search results.

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest you to create an external standalone region and create your advance table and search field in it.

Then deploy the region and relevant files on server and compile your java files and import your external region using jpx importer.

Then using personalization, add a flexible layout in the standard page and under that layout add your region as a flexible content.

Your job is done.

Regards,
Ashok

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will try to do it this way.

Comment: How to use standard page context parameters in this region?

Comment: You should be able to get the values by using pagecontext.getparameter method in the process request method of the controller attached to this region.